# Constructing Dynamic Properties at Runtime in VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, dynamic, properties, introspection

Is there a way to dynamically create properties at runtime in VB .NET using introspection?

e.g. Suppose I had a class

```
Public Class Foo
   Public Property Bar() As String
       get 
           ...
       end get
      set(ByVal value As String)
          ...
      end set
End Class
```

Is there a way to create property Bar at runtime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is [Reflection.Emit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit(v=vs.110).aspx). Not a lot of fun to code, but does what you want.

Comment: this link leads to "this topic is no longer available", fyi in case you want to update it

Answer (score 3):

If you just want a dynamic list of variables, you can always set up a dictionary object as a member of your class, and then set or get a particular dictionary item with a method.

Answer (score 1):

Adding further to my comment, you can add an indexer to your class - which can let you get/set member variable.

EDIT: I am sorry. I didn't know that vb.net doesn't have indexers.
But one can still write code with backing dictionary, which can work like an indexer

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do alter the structure of a class an runtime.  Metadata is fixed at compile time and runs unaltered at runtime.

For the Nitpickers :)

This is not 100% true.  The profiling and ENC APIs allow you to change the structure of metadata at runtime.  But neither are really applicable for this scenario.